# wildfly 17 memory leak with BinderService

Tags: wildfly

I have a wildfly 17.0.1-final server running on java 11.
Since a few weeks I try to make it run continuously instead of restarting it every night. And I encounter some OutOfMemoryError. So I'm seeking for the leak.

**First constatations with JSTAT :**
After a few hours, I can see that memory usage, using jstat (E = eden/young, S = survivor 0+1, O = old, M = metaspace) :

```
 2024-02-05 14:19:01 :   757 Mo            [ E=   56 ; S=   32 ; O=  427 ; M=  242 ]
```

And after a few days :

```
 2024-02-08 14:57:02 :  1562 Mo            [ E=  164 ; S=   20 ; O= 1109 ; M=  269 ]
```

As you can see, "Old" space has grown by 700 Mo in 72 hours

**Memory dumps :**
I have done memory dumps and opened them in MAT (Eclipse Memory Analyzer). The first one, just after wildfly start reports memory occupation of 300 MB. The second one after 60+ hours of work reports a memory occupation of 900 MB.
The second dump reports a memory leak in MSC registry :

> One instance of « org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl » loaded by « Module Class Loader for module org.jboss.msc » occupies 610 317 912 (65,09 %) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of « java.lang.Object[] », loaded by «  », which occupies 610 310 360 (65,08 %) bytes.
>
> Thread « org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl$ServiceThread @ 0x3c01e4968 MSC service thread 1-1 » has a local variable or reference to « org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl @ 0x3c09140e8 » which is on the shortest path to « java.lang.Object[47427] @ 0x3f0d928d8 ». The thread org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl$ServiceThread @ 0x3c01e4968 MSC service thread 1-1 keeps local variables with total size 4 552 (0,00 %) bytes.

If I look at the objects array retaining 600 MB of memory, it seem to contain **32248 instances of org.jboss.as.naming.service.BinderService**.

So, here is the leak. but how can I resolve it ? is there any way to dispose thoses BinderServices ?

I dindn't find anything about a memory leak with BinderService on google.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You may found a bug that leaks memory try opening a issue here:
https://issues.redhat.com/projects/WFLY/issues/WFLY-18700?filter=allopenissues